# node-webkit - AngularJS : Generate PDF and Push to user

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, node-webkit, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to create a PDF and push to user in a standalone node-webkit app. 
Generating PDF is ok but i'm not able to send it to user.
I'have followed indication find here : http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html .

Here my controller :

```
paiApp.controller('pdfCtrl', function($scope) {
  var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
  var blobStream  = require('blob-stream');

  var doc = new PDFDocument;
  stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
  doc.fontSize(15).text('Hello World');
  doc.end();

  stream.on('finish', function() {
    iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    iframe.src = this.toBlobUrl(); //Error here
    // blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf') //Error ...
  });


  // Writting PDF is working
  // ###################################
  // var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
  // var fs = require('fs');

  // doc = new PDFDocument;
  // doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
  // doc.fontSize(15);
  // doc.text('Generate PDF coool!');
  // doc.end();
  // #####################################

});
```

Here my error :

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'toBlobUrl'
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well but recently got it to work for my app. I'm just intending to display a dynamically generated PDF in the browser in a window - so I used an `<object>` -- my client controller code is such:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'SERVERCONTROLLER', responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(function(response){
    var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $scope.mycontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
});
```

Make sure you remember to inject `$sce` to your controller and you should be good to go.

Comment: This answer helped as well as this blog post: http://notjoshmiller.com/server-side-pdf-generation-and-angular-resource/